# Why is this While-Loop stuck in this infinite loop?

Tags: java, while-loop

Does anyone know why this code is stuck in an infinite loop? Once ran without the input of an integer it repeats infinitely "Please enter an integer"

```
class ExceptionHandling {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int foo= getInteger();
    }

    public static int getInteger() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(true)
        {
            int delta = 0;
            try
            {
                delta = in.nextInt();
                return delta;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.out.println("Please enter an integer");
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When does `true` become `false` in `while(true)`?

Comment: Because `in.nextInt()` is throwing an exception. You've entered something that's not an integer, and not removing that from the scanner before trying to read the next int.

Comment: @deHaar the loop can complete without that, if it returns.

Comment: @AndyTurner I know, I just wanted to trigger some more thoughts ;-) I admit, it wasn't done very clearly...